# What is the Chrw value for "% "?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code to find the column name "Total Tech KBA % Completion".

Could someone help me in identifying the % symbol.

```
Set t = .Find("Total Tech KBA " & % & " Completion", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: Did you try recording a macro for searching a `%` in your sheet? Maybe auto-generated code will give some hint.

Comment: Found it from "https://unicode-table.com/en/#0025". Thanks Egan.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me:

```
Dim t As Range
Dim StrtoFind As String

StrtoFind = "Total Tech KBA % Completion"

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
    Set t = .Find(what:=StrtoFind, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not t Is Nothing Then ' make sure Find was successful
        MsgBox StrtoFind & " found at column number " & t.Column
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, it's not working for me, earlier I had used a code like this to identify the hyphen - symbol in my column name and it worked "With Sheets("BASE").Rows(1)
   
Set t = .Find("Goal Progress " & ChrW(45) & " As per Academy ", lookat:=xlWhole)"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, thanks Shai for the quick support.

Got this from the unicode site "https://unicode-table.com/en/#0025"

```
Set t = .Find("Total Tech KBA " & ChrW(37) & " Completion ", lookat:=xlWhole)

   If Not t Is Nothing Then

       Columns(t.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
       Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1")
   Else: MsgBox "Total Tech KBA " & ChrW(37) & " Completion is not found"
   End If
End With
```

Comment: Okay, can anyone explain to me why we're not entering `"%"` but instead using `ChrW(37)` ? Is there more than one % symbol?